# checking for invalid types in python

Tags: python

I need some advise on how best (and to what extent) implement explicitly checking for invalid input in python. Coming from a C++ background with strong type setting, this always has been confusing for me.

So, for discussion let us assume that we have the following method signature:

```
def m(start:float, up:float, down:float):
    pass
```

Now start should be greater than or equal to 0 while the other two should be greater than 0. I could do something like:

```
def m(start:float, up:float=1, down:float=1):
    if start <= 0.0:
        raise ValueError("Error")
    if up< 0.0:
        raise ValueError("Error")
    if down< 0.0:
        raise ValueError("Error")
```

I am guessing this will be fine **as long as** the input type is float or some numeric type which is comparable to float. But in python there is nothing stopping a user from calling the function as:

```
m(start=[], up="Hello", down={})
```

In which case all these comparisons will be meaningless. What is the pythonic way to deal with this situation?

Comment: To let the script puke, since the caller has violated the contract.

Comment: Python typing is getting popular :) look at :
https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

It is new and changing with every python new rel. 3.4, 3.5, 3.5.1 ...
So what's yours ?

Comment: Python will raise a `TypeError`. If your user is a developer, they will read the docs at last, if not there is an horrible bug lying _elsewhere_ in their code, and it's not your fault.

Comment: p.s. your tests are switched, it's `start < 0` and `up <= 0`

Answer (score 1):

You can check that the arguments are floats with `type()`.
For example `if type(start) != float`
Or you can use `isinstance()` function like that:

```
if not isinstance(start, float):
    raise TypeError
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways, the most common is probably: [`EAFP`](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp) (easier to ask forgivness than permission):

```
def m(start:float, up:float=1, down:float=1):
    try:
        if start <= 0.0:
            raise ValueError
        if up < 0.0:
            raise ValueError
        if down < 0.0:
            raise ValueError
    except TypeError:
        # This is just to give a more meaningful error message.
        raise TypeError('Arguments must be numbers.')
```

this will silently fail for python 2 but in python 3 it will raise a TypeError when comparing a not-number to a number. In that sense it will make him aware that he has done something wrong.

The other option is type-checks and the concept of [`LBYL`](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-lbyl) (look before you leap) also known as *defensive programming*:

```
from numbers import Real # or Number if you want to allow compley-types too

def m(start, up=1, down=1):
    # Compare if each argument is a real (floating point) number:
    if not isinstance(start, Real) or not isinstance(up, Real) or not isinstance(down, Real) :
        raise TypeError("Arguments must be numbers.")
    ...
```

Most people (including myself) think EAFP with `try ... except ...` is more pythonic but if you feel more comfortable with `isinstance`-checks then these provide an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your question: `m(start=[], up="Hello", down={})` will crash your program (raise exceptions) as soon as it tries `if start <= 0.0:`. The situation might be more problematic if you have `m('3', '4', '55.27')` because those strings *will* convert to float.

If you want to be defensive in a situation where anything arriving which is not a float or not numeric indicates a logic error in the calling code, then you can test at runtime. `assert` statements raise an AssertionError which is unlikely to be inappropriately caught. So:

```
assert type(start)==float, "start is not a float"
assert type(up)  ==float or type(up)  ==int
assert type(down)==float or type(down)==int
```

These also have the advantage that they are very easy to comment out at a later date, and read (commented or not) somewhat like declarations in other languages if they immediately follow the `def` statement.

You can also check the values with assert:

```
assert  start >= 0
assert up > 0 and down > 0
```

or maybe it's better to raise `ValueError` because these are value errors:

```
if start < 0 or up <= 0 or down <= 0:
     raise ValueError("Bad arguments start={} up={} down={}".format(start,up,down) )
```

The main difference is that raising `ValueError` is intended to signal something which might sensibly be caught by the caller, whereas `assert` is intended to indicate that a logic error has been detected and that immediate program termination is probably best. (Or, propagation to a catch-all handler at the very top of, say, an interactive command parser. There is no hard dividing line.)